# SpriteKit OS X app not accepting keyboard input unless clicked on first

Tags: macos, keyboard, sprite-kit

I really don't know where to start to look for this problem, so here it goes.

I am making an OS X SpriteKit game and after getting the mouse input to work, I went on trying to implement keyboard input. The problem is that whenever I press a keyboard key, the system makes the familiar "keyboard error sound" and no input is accepted into the app. Then clicking into the app window, the keyboard starts accepting keyboard input just fine.

Of course the app window is in the foreground and focused; clicking the window border does not solve the problem, only clicking the window contents does.

Hopefully one can point me into the right direction on what to check to make this work.

Comment: Probably a first responder issue. Try `[window makeFirstResponder:yourView]` once the window has loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

another way i learned to do this is by simply overwriting KeyDown: (KeyUp: is not solving this problem since the error sound is played at the time KeyDown: is done)